# unit testing Javascript function in a JSP file

Tags: java, javascript, unit-testing, junit4

I have a JSP file which has a javascript function with some behavior. How do I unit test this javascript function?

Comment: I'm not sure about what your function is dependent on, but if you can't run JUnit in a Dynamic Web App project (I'm assuming Eclipse here), you can always make a new Java project, copy and paste the function, and test it there?